# Why won't IP mode change to 1 in ESP01 using the AT commands?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-uno-wifi, esp8266webserver

I was trying to send some data to a webpage using an Arduino Uno R3 connected to an ESP01. I simply uploaded the BareMinimum and started sending AT commands through the Serial Monitor. It worked fine for the first time, but now its IPMODE is stuck to 0 (Single IP mode). Everytime I try to set it back to 1 (Multiple IP mode), it throws an error "IPMODE must be 0". I tried resetting the ESP01 but that didn't work.

Comment: you mean AT+CIPMODE? set AT+CIPMUX=0 first

Comment: I'm doing that, for AT+CIPMUX=0, I get "OK" as response, which means that the IP mode is set to 0. But whenever I send AT+CIPMUX=1, it returns "ERROR IP mode must be 0". I don't understand why it MUST be 0, when I have already used this feature once.

Comment: CIPMODE 0 is normal mode and CIPMODE 1 is "passthrough mode".  CIPMUX is : 0 single connection, 1: multiple connections. And multiple connections can only be set when transparent transmission is disabled (AT+CIPMODE=0).